# open3 process leaks?

Tags: perl

I found [a comment](http://www.raphink.info/2008/09/modular-tar-pipe-tar-in-perl.html?showComment=1221544680000#c3971616793857997100) that hints at a problem I think I'm seeing, in which a `fork`ed child of [IPC::Open3](http://p3rl.org/IPC%3a%3aOpen3) is running the main program code instead of just `exec`ing like I would expect.

Does anyone else have experience with "leaking" processes out of IPC::Open3? I looked over the library source, and didn't see anything outrageously wrong.

This is with Perl 5.8.4 (yeah, I know... but it can't be updated) running on Solaris 10.

Comment: Maybe use IPC::Run instead?  It is suggested at the Perl 5.14.0 page for [IPC::Open3](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.0/ext/IPC-Open3/lib/IPC/Open3.pm).  Granted you're stuck on 5.8.4, but maybe IPC::Run works OK there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this has since been fixed, the `open3` from 5.8.4 could throw an exception from the child, meaning both the parent and the child could "return" from `open3`.

While you could handle that, it's a bit complicated.* It would be easier to replace your `IPC/Open3.pm` with the [one](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JESSE/perl-5.14.0/ext/IPC-Open3/lib/IPC/Open3.pm) from a newer Perl.

Better yet, if you don't need something as low-level as IPC::Open3, you could use a higher-level module such as [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun3) (simpler) or [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun) (more powerful).

* — At a minimum,

```
my $parent_pid = $$;
my $pid = eval { open3(...) };
if (!$pid) {
    if ($parent_pid == $$) {
        # Exception in parent.
        die($@);
    } else {
        # Exception in child (pre-exec).
        print STDERR $@;
        _exit(255);
    }
}
```